# Minimal polynomial of a primitive element for Galois extensions with Galois group $S_n$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $K$ be a global field, $f(x)\in K[x]$ be an irreducible separable polynomial and $L$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$. Suppose that the Galois group of $L$ over $K$ is the symmetric group $S_{\deg(f)}$. 
Do you have a simple way to find a defining equation for $L$ in terms of the coefficients of $f$? Essentially what I need is a closed expression for the minimal polynomial of a primitive element (in terms of the coefficients of $f(X)$). I believe this should involve some symmetric polynomial things...

In principle, you get $L$ simply by progressively extending $K$ with the roots of $f(x)$: you will get a sequence $K=L_0\subseteq L_1 \subseteq L_2 \subseteq \dots \subseteq L_{\deg(f)}=L$, where $[L_{i+1}:L_i]=\deg(f)-i$ (this follows because the Galois group is $S_n$, so the roots are essentially indistinguishable). In some sense we know the equation at each step just by euclidean division. Now, I am not sure how to proceed in order to avoid terrible computations, maybe somebody has a nice idea.

If you find it more convenient, you might replace $K$ with $k(t)$, where $k$ is a finite field.

Comment: You’re looking for a polynomial of degree $n!$, yes?

Comment: Yes! thanks for asking.

Comment: I think that your problem is not so much the polynomial for a primitive element as a suitable description of your field. In that field, almost every element is primitive, so that you're bedeviled by an embarrassment of riches. If you have in front of you an efficient set of generators of the splitting field, almost any $K$-linear combination of these will be primitive.

Comment: yes I completely agree, nevertheless it seems difficult to compute the minimal polynomial of any of those primitive elements

Comment: Right, especially if you want some kind of algorithmic method for getting to your objective.